# Casting pointer warning

Tags: c, variables, pointers, casting, warnings

In a C program I am writing, there is a function 
 `void *dereference_physical_page(unsigned int ppn);`

which I call with  `unsigned int* pde = ((unsigned int*)dereference_physical_page(context >> 12))[vaddr >> 22];`

Unfortunately the compiler gives me that warning no matter what I try, and the program needs to have no warnings in order to compile, according to the specifications for this assignment.

edit (I thought I had posted this): The warning is "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast". If i remove the asterisk of unsigned int* pde, this works; however, I want to make pde a pointer.

I am also making pde a pointer because I need its scope to extend beyond that of the function it's in.

Any clues?

Comment: Additionally when I take away the asterisk from the right side it gives me a warning that "cast from pointer to integer of different size" and an error that "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer".

Comment: Would you like us to guess what the warning is?

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing the pointer with `[vaddr >> 22]`, which means the expression has a type of `unsigned int`. Then you're assigning that to an `unsigned int *`. That's where the error is coming from.

Comment: @zach, you've made "pde" a pointer - it's an `unsigned int *`. The fix lies elsewhere.

Comment: @zach You need to make the rhs -- the value assigned to `pde` -- be a pointer; see my answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a pointer to the element you'd have to use `+(vaddr >> 22)` instead of `[vaddr >> 22]`. Please have in mind that pointer arithmetic here counts in sizes of `unsigned` and not in bytes.

But frankly, you don't even seem to be well aware of how pointers work in C. You definitively shouldn't use such hacks before you master these things better.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what "that warning" is, but you are indexing an `unsigned int*`, which yields an `unsigned int`, and then trying to assign it to an `unsigned int*`, which will rightfully give you a warning. If you really need the result to be a pointer, then cast the value from `dereference_physical_page` to `unsigned int**` (two '*'s instead of one). That presumes that the result of `dereference_physical_page(context >> 12)` is the address of an array of `unsigned int*`s and you want the `(vaddr >> 22)`th one.

Answer (score 0):

`((unsigned int*)dereference_physical_page(context >> 12))[vaddr >> 22];`
You are using the type casted pointer returned by `dereference_physical_page` and accessing an array element using this returned pointer...